# How to save data from javafx form to pdf?

Tags: pdf, javafx

I am trying to implement a functionality such that:
When a user clicks on save button, whole data fetched from database by javafx (scene builder)form to get stored into the pdf form. 
I have done with the snapshot, but I want the data obtained via text form to be stored in in pdf file. 
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: You would need a third-party PDF library to generate on-the-fly PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

give "DynamicReports" a try, it's easy to use, and i am using it to generate PDF file in my javafx projects. simple and powerfull.

http://www.dynamicreports.org/

Not only PDF file, it can also help to generates Csv, Docs, Excel, Html, Odt, Pptx, Rtx, Text...

Answer (score 0):

You have a snapshot of your scene.
You can use the JavaFX Printing API, with PrinterJob.
The trick is that when your print anything, your computer's own print spooler will ask you for a destination.
My computer offers "Microsoft Print to PDF" and "Save to PDF".

So the "PDF" feature is trivially easy. All you have to do is, figure out how to use the API.